# python-Recibir los indices de los menores de una lista

Tags: python, indices

Abrí un archivo tipo excel, quiero encontrar a los mas pequeños de una de sus columnas y que me devuelva el indice de ellos. lo que he echo es esto, pero me dice que `index` no se puede invocar

```
tabla['llegada'].index(min(tabla['llegada']))
```

no se si me doy a entender, digamos que `tabla['llegada']=[2,0,3,1,0,2,0]` y necesito los indices de los números `0`.

Comment: Hola Frida, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Usas Pandas (`pandas.read_excel`)? o ¿qué es exactamente `tabla` (tipo de objeto) y cómo la generas? ¿Un diccionario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces la llamada `tabla['llegada']`, lo que te devuelve es un objeto de tipo `pandas.Series` y no una lista. Por eso te falla al hacer la llamada al metodo index, porque ese metodo no es el que se usa para encontrar el indice de una lista, puesto que no lo estas aplicando a una lista. Ademas, aunque aplicaras tu codigo a una lista, esta parte de la instruccion: `.index(min(tabla['llegada']))` solo te daria el indice del primer elemento.

Para buscar el indice de todos los elementos y poder aplicarlo directamente al objeto pandas, puedes usar `numpy.where`, que te devuelve todos los indices del df que cumplan la condicion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tabla = pd.DataFrame({'llegada':[2,0,3,1,0,2,0]})
np.where(tabla['llegada'] == tabla['llegada'].min())

>>>(array([1, 4, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!